# Open spreadsheet by name or create new spreadsheet if none is found

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using the [Google sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) and [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) to append values to a spreadsheet. However, i would like to get the spreadsheet ID by the spreadsheet's name, or create a new spreadsheet if none is found. To be clear, what i mean is what IFTTT does with it's Append to Spreadsheet action. I cannot know the spreadsheet ID beforehand.

[image: Opening spreadsheet by name in IFTTT]

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? When you want to retrieve the spreadsheet ID from the filename of spreadsheet, please use "Files list" of Drive API, because Sheets API cannot achieve it. You can see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).

Comment: @Tanaike thanks, this looks like it could solve the problem, given enough effort. However, it is nowhere near a complete solution. It doesn't **only fetch spreadsheets**, create a **new spreadsheet** if none exists, and it doesn't answer the question. also please note that a answer using the [googleAPIs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) module is prefered.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I would like to understand correctly about what you want to do. From your question, I understood that you want to retrieve the Spreadsheet ID from the filename. Is my understanding correct? But at your reply, it seems that you want to create new Spreadsheet when the Spreadsheet is not existing. I couldn't understand about this from your question. So can you provide the detail information about what you want to do? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @tehhowch I am not asking you to write the code for me. I want a answer that is not purely links. Link-answers are not useful, if the site is unreachable, and they need context (that has been provided by Tanaike, thanks!). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: My atempt is buerried deep within pages of google searches and google RESTful API docs. There are many similar APIs, and i simply want awell researched, best practices answer. My question is quite clear, even including a example that you can use that shows the results I want to be able to acheve.

Comment: I know is not a code writing service. It's a wiki site, as Jeff Atwood has said himself. I am a individual on the internet. what makes you think I can afford to pay someone, or even have a buget? especialy if i can afford to wait 7 days to have my question answered, before even putting a bounty on it. a commercial product would not stand that delay, and their team of multiple engeneers wouldn't have even needed to use SO. also, this, i think, would be a common script that google users that like to DIY a bit would use a lot.

Comment: Please, be kind with your words. They will remain forever.

Comment: Here's the summary of the task: Use the Drive API to search the user's drive for the given name and desired mimetype. If you find a result... that's your result. If you don't find a result.. create the spreadsheet. You can create it with either the Drive API (which will let you configure *where* it gets created) or with the Sheets REST API (which will let you control the data present in the sheet initially). With either method, you can then use the other API to do what the first could not (either create in root then move, or create in destination and then initialize)

Comment: Exactly. but should i use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters or https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref, and how do iterate throug the results and decide weather they are sheets or not. Can i do it with [google-api-nodejs-client] or not? should i use the Sheets API or the Drive API? these are all things that mean it should be on SO, as a wiki.

Comment: Why do you think someone is going to write this for you, when you have written **nothing** of your own? You need to make an attempt to solve your issue. I've already walked you through what needs to happen - you just have to write it. If you then have a **specific error** and can show **specific work** that attempts to resolve said error, your question would be much more well-received. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi tehhowch. As said, I am not asking you to write my code for me. I simply want a answer, and the reason i asume there will be code is because all the [b](stackoverflow.com/a/23669825/9761034)[e](stackoverflow.com/a/168488/9761034)[s](stackoverflow.com/a/3426956/9761034)[t](stackoverflow.com/a/524715/9761034) answers include code. However, you do not need to do anything, as ssemilla has answered the question with a good answer, that makes my rather janky setup, with IFTTT webhooks and stuff ([based off of this](https://v.gd/JsZi12)), redundant. and please stop being so rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to authenticate with `googleapis`, here is a minimal example how to query the Drive API to search for spreadsheets with a specific name and using the Sheets API to create if there is none.

```
// auth is google.auth.OAuth2()
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth})
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth})

var fileName = 'yourSpreadSheetName'
var mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'

drive.files.list({
    q: `mimeType='${mimeType}' and name='${fileName}'`,
    fields: 'files(id, name)'
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('drive files error: ' + err)
    const files = res.data.files
    if (files.length) {

        // There is an existing spreadsheet(s) with the same filename
        // The spreadsheet Id will be in files[x].id
        console.log(`found spreadsheet with id: ${files[0].id}`)

    } else {

        // Create spreadsheet with filename ${fileName}
        sheets.spreadsheets.create({
            resource: {
                properties: { title: fileName }},
            fields: 'spreadsheetId'
        }, (err, spreadsheet) => {
            if (err) return console.log('spreadsheets create error: ' + err)
            // The spreadsheet Id will be in ${spreadsheet.data.spreadsheetId}
            console.log(`created spreadsheet with id: ${spreadsheet.data.spreadsheetId}`)
        })
    }
});
```